# A weak version of the Whitehead Theorems

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology, cw-complexes

Let  $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a map between CW-complexes $X$ and $Y$. By the Whitehead Theorems, if one of the conditions:

1- (homotopy version) $\pi_n (f):\pi_n (X)\longrightarrow \pi_n (Y)$ is an isomorphism for all $n\geq 1$,

or

2- (homology version) $\pi_1 (f):\pi_1 (X)\longrightarrow \pi_1 (Y)$ and $H_n (\tilde{f}):H_n (\tilde{X})\longrightarrow H_n (\tilde{Y})$ are isomorphisms for all $n\geq 2$,

hold, then  there is a map $g:Y\longrightarrow X$ such that $g\circ f\simeq id_X$ and $f\circ g\simeq id_Y$.

Question: Is there any weaker condition (with respect to above conditions) under which there is a map $g:Y\longrightarrow X$ such that we have only $g\circ f\simeq id_X$?

Comment: This would not be a weak version of the Whitehead theorem in that it doesn’t follow from the Whitehead theorem. Actually I think it will be much harder to say anything about this.

Comment: You probably want to mumble connected somewhere

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for the comment. I agree with you.

Comment: @ThomasRot I don't understand your mean.

Comment: (2) is true if $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected, or more generally simple, or even more generally nilpotent spaces, but not for general CW complexes. (On the other hand, for nilpotent spaces you do not need to require $\pi_1$-isomorphism, it follows form the homology isomorphism).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196576/homology-equivalence-and-isomorphism-on-pi-1-not-enough-for-homotopy-equivale

Comment: @GregoryArone My question is completely different from your answer. I asked: under what condition we can find a map $g:Y\longrightarrow X$ so that $g\circ f\simeq id_X$.

Comment: @M.Ramana I was not trying to answer your question, just making a comment. I don't have a good answer, but one easy thing you can say is: If $X$ is an Eilenberg-Mac Lane space, and $f$ is split injective in homology, then there exists a $g$ like you ask for.

Comment: @GregoryArone Yes I understood. Thank you so much for your comment. That's true. Your are right. Because of the existence of an equivalent functor between categories groups and  Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, we can conclude your claim.

Comment: @M.Ramana: The homotopy groups only see the topology of the connected component of the basepoint (The map that sends two points to one is not a homotopy equivalence but induces an iso on all homotopy groups).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a map $f\colon X\to Y$ of finite CW complexes such that $K(p,n)_*(f)$ is injective for all primes $p$ and integers $n\geq 0$ (where $K(p,n)$ is Morava $K$-theory).  Then the Nilpotence Theorem of Hopkins, Devinatz and Smith implies that the map $\Sigma^kf^{(m)}\colon \Sigma^kX^{(m)}\to\Sigma^kY^{(m)}$ has a left inverse $g$ for sufficiently large $k$ and $m$.  This may not seem very satisfactory but I think that it is the best that you can reasonably hope to do.  The question of whether a map has a left inverse is just intrinsically much more subtle than the question of whether it is an equivalence.

One can also say that in the category of finite spectra, a map $f\colon X\to Y$ has a left inverse iff $\pi_*^S(f)\colon \pi_*^S(X)\to\pi_*^S(Y)$ is injective, provided that Freyd's Generating Hypothesis is correct.  But the Generating Hypothesis has been any open question for fifty years now, which is another indication that the problem is intrinsically hard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This can be so useful for working on these problems. Thanks for more explanations.